# Template type deduction problem

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++11, rvalue-reference

I've got a `variant` class. It has a pair of constructors:

```
/// Construct and fill.
template <typename T>
inline
variant (const T& t)
{
  YYASSERT (sizeof (T) <= S);
  new (buffer.raw) T(t);
}

template <typename T>
inline
variant (T&& t)
{
  YYASSERT (sizeof (T) <= S);
  new (buffer.raw) T(std::move(t));
}
```

Now I've called those constructors in this code:

```
parser::symbol_type
parser::make_IDENTIFIER (const Wide::ParsedFile::Identifier*& v)
{
return symbol_type (token::IDENTIFIER, v);
}
```

`symbol_type` takes a `variant` as it's second argument in this specific constructor, and `v` is being implicitly converted.

However, MSVC will try to use the rvalue reference constructor instead of using the other constructor, resulting in a compilation error when it attempts to `new` a reference. Why is that, and how can I make it stop?

Comment: Do you have a minimal, standalone example?

Comment: @James: Unfortunately, the code is automatically generated by an external program and I'm not particularly familiar with it, so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You generally should not overload a templated `T&&` function.  You should instead have the single function which forwards:

```
template <typename T>
inline
variant (T&& t)
{
  typedef typename std::remove_reference<T>::type Tr;
  YYASSERT (sizeof (Tr) <= S);
  new (buffer.raw) Tr(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

This has the functionality of your two overloads, while avoiding the problem of picking the wrong one.

I believe (not positive) that these are the two variants in your overload set:

```
varaint<const Wide::ParsedFile::Identifier*>(const Wide::ParsedFile::Identifier*const&)
varaint<const Wide::ParsedFile::Identifier*&>(const Wide::ParsedFile::Identifier*&)
```

And the second one wins because it is more specialized than the first (I'm making an educated guess, I'm not 100% positive).

Comment: That doesn't actually *solve* the problem, because T is still a reference type and the construction will still fail.

Comment: @DeadMG:  I think you'll also need a `std::remove_reference<T>::type` for the placement new type (and perhaps a `std::remove_cv`?  I'm not 100% sure).  Alternatively, if you really do want two overloads, you can use `enable_if` to prohibit the `T&&` overload from being instantiated with a reference-type `T`.

Comment: The first variant has as its parameter a `const Wide::ParsedFile::Identifier * const&`. So the second wins in overload resolution because it does not have a const reference parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The second template would be a better match, because the `const` specifiers are in different places in your function and in the first constructor.

In the first overload you will have T being deduced as

```
const Wide::ParsedFile::Identifier*
```

And then creating a const reference to that type. That adds an extra const.